# How can I properly reload the UIViewController after dismiss method is called?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift5, navigationcontroller

I have 2 viewControllers named vcA and vcB.
vcA has navigationController and vcB is just viewController which don't have navigationController.
I saved text data in a file in vcB, and I wanna show that text in vcA when I come back to vcA after the dismiss method is called.
I thought reloading vcA after dismiss is called is the proper way to show text, but I figured out that it might be difficult to do that between vcA and vcB, because vcA has navigationController but vcB doesn't have navigationController.
How can I refresh vcA?

Comment: You have to do it manually.

Comment: welcome to SO ..your ques is unclear here to understand, specifically what you need is transition between two controllers or data passing between them. [Also read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use self.present over self.dismiss. Like this:

let vc = vcA()

*And here you can pass data. For example, if vcA() has a var called text that is a string you can use vc.text = "something". And this data will go with the self.present method*

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value back to the presenting view controller using the protocol/delegate pattern.  Following is an example of how to pass a text from a text field in `vcB` to `vcA` as `vcB` is being dismissed so you can substitute that with the value you want to pass.

```swift
protocol ValuePassingDelegate {
    func didPassValue(of text: String)
}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, ValuePassingDelegate {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)))
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "Initial text"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonHandler() {
        let vcB = ViewControllerB()
        vcB.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
    }
    
    func didPassValue(of text: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.label.text = text
        }
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)))
    var delegate: ValuePassingDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.addSubview(textField)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        delegate?.didPassValue(of: textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I followed for this purpose is :

in vcB I added:
`internal var senderVC: UIViewController?`

in vcA I added:
`vcB.senderVC = self`

in vcB I added:
`if let firstVC = self.senderVC as? vcA { firstVC.tableView.reloadData(); }`